# Is there a name for a differential equation that has a discrete, non-continuous part?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, discrete-calculus

I am studying an equation that looks like $x'' + \omega^2 x = 0$, where $\omega^2$ is discrete and only takes on values like $C m(m + 2)$ where $C$ is a constant and $m = 1, 2, 3, \dots$

I'm pretty confused regarding whether the solutions would be different from the case where $\omega^2$ is continuous.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: "Mixed Difference and Differential Equation"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that $C>0$, then the usual trigonometric solutions work with angular frequency
$$
\omega = \sqrt{Cm(m+2)}, 
$$
so the general solution $m \geq 1$ looks like
$$
x(t) = c_1 \sin \omega t + c_2 \cos \omega t, 
$$
where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are arbitrary constants that depend on initial/boundary values. You can view this family of sinusoids [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/a92ftrx2yc).

Comment: Thank you! Just to clarify, so this is not a "difference" equation?

Comment: I interpret $x''$ to mean the second derivative of $x$, so this is an (ordinary) differential equation.